# Why are worms, centipedes and snakes long?

Tags: evolution

Some animals have mostly distinct, non-repeating body parts, each performing a particular function. However, some kinds of animals, such as worms, centipedes and snakes, have a long body that appears to be longitudinally uniform in most of its length. What is the evolutionary sense to that? For instance, what advantage does having a hundred of limbs convey to a centipede, while a spider is happy with a tenfold less?

Comment: We have an ontogenetic answer ([the Oct4 gene is responsible for the continued growth of snakes](https://www.cell.com/developmental-cell/comments/S1534-5807(16)30513-5)), but it doesn't look like we yet have any good explanation for why it has happened. My take would be for the way snakes have been feeding. It helps them by having longer stomachs that can accumulate more preys in one hunt, then they can rest for a while.